# Why new laravel 9 project with github shows "git: 'auth' is not a git command. See 'git --help'"?

Tags: laravel, github, laravel-9, github-cli

I created a new project with `laravel new testproj --github`, in order to create a repository in github, but it keeps saying `git: 'auth' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`.
Why is that happening?